# git commit can't find (global) config running in cron job

Tags: git, cron, git-commit

I want to commit some file changes using a cron job calling a script with the following line in roots crontab

```
0 * * * * cd /files/ && ./backup.sh >/tmp/cronlog 2>/tmp/cronerror
```

the script looks as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

… prepare the files for the backup …

echo "commit changes …"
git add -u
git commit -m "backup"
git push
```

Prior to the cron setup I've also set `user.email` and `user.name` for the root user and I've checked that the script runs if I call if from the command line.

But in `/tmp/cronerror` I receive the following well known message.

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
…
```

I've also tried setting `HOME=/root` in the script but this doesn't seam to make a difference.

Is there a way of telling the git command where to find the global git-config when running in a cron job?

Comment: Interesting.  Did you use `HOME=/root; export HOME` or `export HOME=/root`?  (Or put `HOME=/root` in front of each git command, but that's the long way.)

Comment: I just wrote `HOME=/root` in a line before the `echo`, should I've used `export`?

Comment: I've now also added an `echo $HOME`, which already is set to `/root`. And even putting `HOME=/root` in front of each git command doesn't change the situation.

Comment: OK, so it's not that `$HOME` is wrong, it's something else.  What else, I don't know.  It's interesting that storing the config in the local repository works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is to use `git config …` without `--global` option which stores the configuration in the current repository, where git is able to find it.