# git commit doesn't work from a cron job, although git pull does work

Tags: git, cron

In my crontab, I have the following line:

```
48 14 * * * bash /home/erelsgl/git/erel-sites/add-commit-push.bash "from home" 2&>1 >> /home/erelsgl/logs/backup_from_home.log
```

The script does what its name implies - add, commit and push:

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
cd $DIR
echo --------------------
date
echo == add ==
/usr/bin/git add -A
echo == commit ==
/usr/bin/git commit -m "$1"
echo == pull ==
/usr/bin/git pull
echo == push ==
/usr/bin/git push
```

As seen in the log file, the "commit" does nothing while the "pull" works fine:

```
Fri Oct 23 14:48:01 IDT 2015
== add ==
== commit ==
== pull ==
Already up-to-date.
== push ==
```

I ran the exact same command, a minute later, from the command line, and got the following log, which means that the commit did happen:

```
Fri Oct 23 14:49:31 IDT 2015
== add ==
== commit ==
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
== pull ==
Already up-to-date.
== push ==
```

What is the problem in running commit from a cron job?

NOTE: I also did the same experiment with an actual change in a test file. I found out that, indeed, the commit didn't happen from the crontab (nothing was pushed to upstream) but did happen from the command line.

Comment: `git push` requires a .gitconfig file to set things like the author and email. git will not push without those settings present. It looks like - because youre running it through cron - git cannot locate this file because cron runs in a different environment. You could also try adding `2>&1` to your cron script so you also get stderr output in your log.

Comment: You should add `2>&1` as @Protagonist says , there probably is an error with git commit, either `$1` is empty and git is complaining that the message is empty, either no files were added and git is complaining because the commit is empty

Comment: I added "2>&1". Now, when I run from command line, there is indeed a message saying that there is nothing to commit. But when  run from crontab, no message appears (see my edit). It seems that "git commit" does not run at all! why?

Comment: Which users crontab entry is it?

Comment: @iltempo it is my crontab (user erelsgl).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cron` uses `sh` by default, so try, as described in "[How to redirect output to a file from within cron?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52332/7490)":

- no 'bash'
- with `2>&1` at the end

That is:

```
48 14 * * * /home/erelsgl/git/erel-sites/add-commit-push.bash "from home" >> /home/erelsgl/logs/backup_from_home.log 2>&1
```

And put in your bash script a [shebang directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29):

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
cd $DIR
...
```

---

Another form would be to use a bash command line (as in "[Redirecting the output of a cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14983135/6309)"):

```
48 14 * * *  /bin/bash -l -c '/path/to/script >> ./log/my_log.log 2>&1'
```

---

> After changing the order of redirection as recommended, my log file indeed shows a long error message saying:

```
Please tell me who you are. 
Run git config --global user.email "you@example.com" 
    git config --global user.name "Your Name" 
to set your account's default identity
```

> I already did this in my account, but the cron job probably does not find the config file. How can I make it find the correct git config file?

The cron job is likely to run with another account (or root): its global git config (`~/.gitconfig`) won't be the same as the one you set with your user account.

One simple solution is to [repeat those git config (without --global) inside the target git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25157475/6309): that will register the user id in the repo itself, instead of relying on a global config which is not shared across accounts.

Comment: Done, but it did not help... (why would $BASH_SOURCE[0] have any effect on git commit?)

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi OK. I have rewritten the answer, based on http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52332/7490

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi I have edited the answer with another option

Comment: OK, after changing the order of redirection as recommended, my log file indeed shows a long error message saying: "*** Please tell me who you are.    Run  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"   git config --global user.name "Your Name" to set your account's default identity.".   I already did this in my account, but the cron job probably does not find the  config file. How can I make it find the correct git config file?  I have the same problem whether I run the script with or without "/bin/bash".

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi the cron job is likely to run with another account (or root): its global git config (~/.gitconfig) won't be the same as the one you set with your user account.

Comment: OK, so how do I tell it to use my .gitconfig?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi I have edited the answer with a proposed solution.